# Friendly url in apache2

Tags: apache, .htaccess, friendly-url

Now, have the next .htaccess (in the root folder):

```
Options -Indexes
Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine on

# Ocultar extension php (hidden .php)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

# Url amigable (frienly url)
RewriteBase /
Rewriterule ^owner/servicios/(.+)/$ owner/servicios.php?servicio=$1
```

I expect when the user access try to "domain.com.ar/owner/index/" show the page "index.php". This not work, but, i access "domain.com.ar/owner/index" works.
On the other hand, when the user try to access "domain.com.ar/owner/servicios/servicio_uno/", $_GET value of "servicio" should be "servicio_uno", but is: "servicio_uno/.php/servicio_uno ".
And "domain.com.ar/owner/servicios/servicio_uno" shows 500 internal error.
Any ideas ?.

Answer (score 0):

depending on where is your htaccess located (root directory or /owner directory)

```
//if in root
RewriteBase /
Rewriterule ^owner/servicios/(.+)/$ owner/servicios.php?servicio=$1


//if in owner directory
RewriteBase owner/
Rewriterule ^servicios/(.+)/$ servicios.php?servicio=$1
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, this works !. The url is: "local.pilarme.com.ar/owner/servicios/servicio_uno", but $_GET['servicio'] have "servicio_uno/.php/servicio_uno" value (???)

Comment: The hidden extension are causing the error, how can solves ?.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /owner/servicios/

RewriteRule (.*) /owner/servicios.php?servicio=$1
RewriteRule ^owner/servicios/servicios.php/(.*) servicios.php?servicios=servicios=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is the .htaccess still in the root folder?

Comment: Does the file contain anything else? The solution is easy as long as there isn't anything else affecting it.

Comment: the file contains only that.